# use zlib to uncompress incoming data(compressed data) from a tcp connection

Tags: tcp, zlib, inflate, compression

I have a client and a server, the client sent compressed chunks(compressed with zlib compress() function, and server doesn't each chunk's size) through tcp to the server. Question is how do I uncompress those received data in the server side? The data send(write) and receive(read) are persistent so I cant wait until the client receive all the data and then uncompress.

Comment: Did you develop the protocol you're using to put zlib on top of TCP? If not, ask the person who did. If you developed it, how can you not already know? You're asking us how something is designed to work without even telling us what that something *is*.

Comment: Some one else develop the protocol on top of TCP Im working with, my work is to add compression to it. I have finish the compress part, now my question is with uncompress. Every time I call the linux read() function from certain FD the returned buffer may contain incomplete part of chunk. So how can I handle this. @DavidSchwartz

Comment: I'm talking about the protocol for adding compression. If you developed it, you should know how its framing works. If not, you're trying to implement a protocol that hasn't actually been designed. That will almost never work. (How can you have even started the compress part if you don't know how decompression will work?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to put compression on top of TCP, you need some protocol for doing so. Before such a protocol is implemented, it should be designed. That design must specify how the receiver will do the framing so that the sender can be implemented to work with that receiver design. You need to take a huge step back and figure out how the protocol as a whole is going to work. You should definitely have done this before you started implementing.

You could develop a streaming protocol for compression on top of TCP (where the receiver can decompress data as whole blocks of decompressed data are available without needing explicit framing). You could develop a block protocol for compression on top of TCP, but that will require some kind of actual protocol for finding the ends of the blocks. You may have to consider when data is "pushed" (or flushed) on the compression side, depending on the details of the protocol on top of you.

Design the system before you start implementing, otherwise you'll find at some point you have no idea what the implementation is supposed to be.